# Switching on/off test suits with boost

Tags: c++, boost-test

I have a `Class A` (implemented in `A.cpp` and `A.h`). I have created a file `testA.cpp` and implemented tests for the class A. testA.cpp basically has the form:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TestA
...
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_A)
...
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testA1) { ... }
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testA2) { ... }
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testA3) { ... }
...
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

This generates all that is needed to run the tests (the main file, etc.)

Now I would like to add an additional `class B` (implemented in `B.cpp` and `B.h`) and implement an additional test suit for B in `testB.cpp` and extend my test module to contain `TestA` and `TestB`.

Must I give up at least autogeneration of the main function that registeres the test suits if the test suits reside in different files? How can I organize the suits so I can easily switch on/off individual suits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I found the following solution for the problem:

- I have created main file for tests: tests.cpp with the following content:

> ```
>  #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Tests
>
>  #include "testA.cpp"
>  #include "testB.cpp"
> ```

the include CPP Files contain individual test suits. Any better solution is very welcome